# git: get current working dir

Tags: git, working-directory

How I can get current working dir from console using `git`?

something like: if I'm in: `~/projects/someproject/somesubfolder/`, the console command should say `/home/va1en0k/someproject/` (if there is a `.git/` folder in this directory or something like this)

or if `GIT_WORKING_DIR` is set, it should return it. or whatever Git uses to determine it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $( cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup); pwd)
```

Comment: I looked at git-rev-parse(1). It seems like "git rev-parse --show-toplevel" will suffice. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Is the outer command substitution really needed here? Running in a subshell (`(cd … ; pwd)`) may be enough. Please see [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: The problem is, that `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and your comment both dont work when you are in the `.git` dir e.g. in a hook-script

Answer (score 20):

Simple:

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

Comment: How is this different from 'valya Apr 10 '11 at 19:03' comment below the accepted answer, we can all miss things.

Comment: A comment is not an answer, it cannot be accepted.

Comment: `--show-toplevel` will be an absolute path apparently, and `--show-cdup` will be relative to cwd.