# What is wrong with “echo $(stuff)” or “echo `stuff`”?

Tags: shell-script, sh, echo

I used one of the following

```
echo $(stuff)
echo `stuff`
```

(where `stuff` is e.g. `pwd` or `date` or something more complicated).

Then I was told this syntax is wrong, bad practice, non-elegant, excessive, redundant, overly complicated, cargo cult programming, noobish, naive etc.

But the command *does* work, so what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: It's redundant and therefore should not be used.  Compare with Useless Use Of Cat: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: `echo $(echo $(echo $(echo$(echo $(stuff)))))` also *does* work, and still you probably wouldn't use it, right? ;-)

Comment: What are you trying to do with that expansion, exactly?

Comment: @curiousguy I'm trying to help other users, hence my answer below. Recently, I've seen at least three questions that use this syntax. Their authors were trying to do… various `stuff`. :D

Comment: Also, don't we all agree that it's unwise to confine oneself to an echo chamber?? ;-)

Comment: Does the tag [tag:sh] imply a strictly `/bin/sh` question?

Comment: @curiousguy "The standard command language interpreter". I added this to indicate shells compatible and/or derived from `sh` (e.g. not [tag:Powershell]). It's not about any single shell; it's about the concept of using `echo` with command substitution this way.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski There are mostly compatible shells with support for all basic constructs but with sometimes different semantics. `zsh` is interesting.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## tl;dr

The sole `stuff` would *most probably* work for you.

---

## Full answer

#### What happens

When you run `foo $(stuff)`, this is what happens:

1. `stuff` gets executed, in a subshell, setting it up requires some time;
2. Its output (stdout), instead of being printed, replaces `$(stuff)` in the argument of `foo`; Stderr still goes to /dev/stderr.
3. The string generated by the execution of `stuff` and captured by `$(...)`, as in **not** quoted, is subject to globbing and splitting.
4. First splitting will break (split) the string at any of the characters in IFS, by default `<space><tab><newline>`.
5. Then globbing, in which any `*`, `?` and valid `[]` will be replaced with a **list** of matching files.
6. then `foo` runs, its command line arguments obviously depend on what `stuff` returned.

This `$(…)` mechanism is called "command substitution". In your case the main command is `echo` which basically prints its command line arguments to stdout separated by a single space. So whatever `stuff` tries to print to stdout is captured, modified, expanded and given to `echo` and then printed to stdout by `echo`.

If you want the output of `stuff` to be printed to stdout, just run the sole `stuff`.

The `` `…` `` syntax serves the same purpose as `$(…)` (under the same name: "command substitution"), there are few differences though, so you cannot blindly interchange them. See [this FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/108618).

---

#### Should I avoid `echo $(stuff)` no matter what?

There is a reason you may want to use `echo $(stuff)` if you know what you're doing. For the same reason you should avoid `echo $(stuff)` if you don't really know what you're doing.

The point is `stuff` and `echo $(stuff)` are no way equivalent. The latter means calling split+glob operator on the output of `stuff` with the default value of `$IFS`. Double quoting the command substitution prevents this. Single quoting the command substitution makes it no longer be a command substitution.

To observe this when it comes to splitting run these commands:

```
echo "a       b"
echo $(echo "a       b")
echo "$(echo "a       b")"  # the shell is smart enough to identify the inner and outer quotes
echo '$(echo "a       b")'
```

And for globbing:

```
echo "/*"
echo $(echo "/*")
echo "$(echo "/*")"  # the shell is smart enough to identify the inner and outer quotes
echo '$(echo "/*")'
```

As you can see `echo "$(stuff)"` is equivalent(-ish*) to `stuff`. You could use it but what's the point of complicating things this way?

On the other hand if you *want* the output of `stuff` to undergo splitting+globbing then you *may* find `echo $(stuff)` useful. It has to be your conscious decision though.

There are commands generating output that should be evaluated (which includes splitting, globbing and more) and run by the shell, so `eval "$(stuff)"` is a possibility (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437357/108618)). I have never seen a command that needs its output to undergo additional splitting+globbing before being *printed*. Deliberately using `echo $(stuff)` seems very uncommon.

---

#### What about `var=$(stuff); echo "$var"`?

Good point. This snippet:

```
var=$(stuff)
echo "$var"
```

should be equivalent to `echo "$(stuff)"` equivalent(-ish*) to `stuff`. If it's the whole code, just run `stuff` instead.

If, however, you need to use the output of `stuff` more than once then this approach

```
var=$(stuff)
foo "$var"
bar "$var"
```

is usually better than

```
foo "$(stuff)"
bar "$(stuff)"
```

Even if `foo` is `echo` and you get `echo "$var"` in your code, it may be better to keep it this way. Things to consider:

1. With `var=$(stuff)` `stuff` runs once; even if the command is fast, avoiding computing the same output twice is the right thing. Or maybe `stuff` has effects other than writing to stdout (e.g. creating a temporary file, starting a service, starting a virtual machine, notifying a remote server), so you don't want to run it multiple times.
2. If `stuff` generates time-depending or somewhat random output, you may get inconsistent results from `foo "$(stuff)"` and `bar "$(stuff)"`. After `var=$(stuff)` the value of `$var` is fixed and you can be sure `foo "$var"` and `bar "$var"` get identical command line argument.

In some cases instead of `foo "$var"` you may want (need) to use `foo $var`, especially if `stuff` generates *multiple* arguments for `foo` (an array variable may be better if your shell supports it). Again, know what you're doing. When it comes to `echo` the difference between `echo $var` and `echo "$var"` is the same as between `echo $(stuff)` and `echo "$(stuff)"`.

---

#### *Equivalent(*-ish*)?

I said `echo "$(stuff)"` is equivalent(-ish) to `stuff`. There are at least two issues that make it not exactly equivalent:

1. `$(stuff)` runs `stuff` in a subshell, so it's better to say `echo "$(stuff)"` is equivalent(-ish) to `(stuff)`. Commands that affect the shell they run in, if in a subshell, don't affect the main shell.

   In this example `stuff` is `a=1; echo "$a"`:

   ```
    a=0
    echo "$(a=1; echo "$a")"      # echo "$(stuff)"
    echo "$a"
   ```

   Compare it with

   ```
    a=0
    a=1; echo "$a"                # stuff
    echo "$a"
   ```

   and with

   ```
    a=0
    (a=1; echo "$a")              # (stuff)
    echo "$a"
   ```

   Another example, start with `stuff` being `cd /; pwd`:

   ```
    cd /bin
    echo "$(cd /; pwd)"           # echo "$(stuff)"
    pwd
   ```

   and test `stuff` and `(stuff)` versions.
2. [`echo` is not a good tool to display uncontrolled data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/108618). This `echo "$var"` we were talking about should have been `printf '%s\n' "$var"`. But since the question mentions `echo` and since the most probable solution is not to use `echo` in the first place, I decided not to introduce `printf` up until now.
3. `stuff` or `(stuff)` will interleave stdout and stderr output, while `echo $(stuff)` will print all the stderr output from `stuff` (which runs first), and only then the stdout output digested by `echo` (which runs last).
4. `$(…)` strips off any trailing newline and then `echo` adds it back. So `echo "$(printf %s 'a')" | xxd` gives different output than `printf %s 'a' | xxd`.
5. Some commands (`ls` for example) work differently depending if the standard output is a console or not; so `ls | cat` does not the same `ls` does. Similarly `echo $(ls)` will work differently than `ls`.

   Putting `ls` aside, in a general case *if* you have to force this other behavior then `stuff | cat` is better than `echo $(stuff)` or `echo "$(stuff)"` because it doesn't trigger all the other issues mentioned here.
6. Possibly different exit status (mentioned for completeness of this wiki answer; for details see [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1353335/432690) that deserves credit).

Comment: One more difference: the `stuff` way will interleave `stdout` and `stderr` output, while ``echo `stuff` `` will print all the `stderr` output from `stuff`, and only then the `stdout` output.

Comment: And this is another example for: There can hardly be too many quotes in bash scripts. `echo $(stuff)` can put you into far more troubles as `echo "$(stuff)"` if you do not want globbing and expansion explicitly.

Comment: One more slight difference: `$(…)` strips off any trailing newline and then `echo` adds it back. So `echo "$(printf %s 'a')" | xxd` gives different output than `printf %s 'a' | xxd`.

Comment: You should not forget that some commands (`ls` for example) work differently depending if the standard output is a console or not; so `ls | cat` does not the same `ls` does. And of course `echo $(ls)` will work differently than `ls`.

Comment: @Ruslan The answer is now community wiki. I have added your useful comment to the wiki. Thank you.

Comment: @derobert The answer is now community wiki. I have added your useful comment to the wiki. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinRosenau The answer is now community wiki. I have added your useful comment to the wiki. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, and to my surprise when I tried it today, `echo $(echo "/*")` behaves differently in `zsh` than in `bash` -- `zsh` just prints `/*`.

Comment: @JakeRobb Because `zsh` treats [unquoted command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) as if it was quoted.

Answer (score 6):

Another difference: The sub-shell exit code is lost, so the exit code of `echo` is retrieved instead.

```
> stuff() { return 1
}
> stuff; echo $?
1
> echo $(stuff); echo $?
0
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you *explain* the difference you are demonstrating? Thanks

Comment: I believe that this shows that the return code`$?` will be the return code of `echo` (for `echo $(stuff)`) instead of the one `return`ed by `stuff`. The `stuff` function `return 1` (exit code), but `echo` sets it to "0" regardless of the return code of `stuff`. Still should be in the answer.

Comment: the return value from the subshell has been lost