# How can I get the bash interpreter to interpret the ~ character?

Tags: macos, bash

as the home directory?

I tried all 3 methods below but it just echos out the ~.

```
NAME="~/_root/repo/"

echo $NAME
echo "$NAME"
echo "${NAME}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the shell expand the ~ before assigning it to NAME, by removing the quotes on the assignment statement.

```
NAME=~/_root/repo/
echo "$NAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no function for that. A tilde inside a string is just a tilde. You'll have to manually match and replace it with the value of $HOME:

```
var=${var}/
var=${var/#"~/"/"$HOME/"}
var=${var%/}
```

If you use 'eval', it interprets *everything* – it expands the tilde, but it also expands wildcards, it also expands variable substitutions, it also parses spaces, quotes, array syntax, and so on.

```
var="~/dir/file.txt"
eval "var=$var"

var="~/dir with spaces/file.txt"
eval "var=$var"

var="~/dir/file (1).txt"
eval "var=$var"
```

Comment: Isn't there a way for the bash shell to act like a bash shell ... for example when I am in the bash shell and I type `cd ~` it knows to change directory to my home directory.

Comment: That's a different thing from what you originally asked. There's `eval` for interpreting a _whole command line_ as if "typed in". There isn't anything for performing certain individual expansion steps.

Comment: The following answer is shorter than grawity's, but I'm making as a comment as I wish not to compete with grawity's answer, since the root of these answers are fundamentally the same.  You can probably get desirable results by trying this: `echo $( eval echo $( echo ${NAME} ) )` note the curly braces are different than the parenthesis

Comment: @TOOGAM: That's a little redundant, you get the same with `eval echo $NAME` already.

Comment: @TOOGAM Nice combo. :) Please see [this](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690).