# Using Shell date command on macOS

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to convert a date string into epoch time in bash on macOS. I understand that the Mac's version of `date` is subtly different from on Linux - and I can't work out where I'm going wrong.

Here's an example expression I'm trying:

```
echo "$(date -j -u -f "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" +%s "08/08/20 20:20:00")"
```

This returns:

```
date: nonexistent time
```

Any clues?!

Comment: [Why `echo`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: Just so I can see what's being output from this single command whilst I troubleshoot; my script won't be using echo here.

Comment: Thanks Kamil - didn't notice that was a link. Point taken about the superfluous `echo` - definitely noobish!

Answer (score 2):

Ok - just needed a break from it in order to get my head around it. :-) What I needed to use is this:

```
date -j -u -f "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S" +%s "08/08/20 20:20:00"
```

(That is, `%y` instead of `%Y`)

The `%Y` was expecting a 4-digit year, so giving it `08/08/20` was referring to a day in 20AD - which is before the beginning of epoch time - hence nonexistent time.