# How can the convert command's output be passed/piped instead of saved to a file?

Tags: bash-scripting, imagemagick, pipe, base64

I made a HTML file with images as base64. I started bash-scripting to make a folders images be base64-printed into this html-file. I worked, I share the code:

```
cat html_head.txt > fil.html
for i in *.jpg; do echo $(cat html_image_cell_start.txt) "data:image/jpeg;base64, " $(base64 $i) $(cat html_image_cell_end.txt) >> fil.html; done
cat html_foot.txt >> fil.html
```

But these image files were previously made by resizing (original images) using a script like:

```
for i in *.jpg; do convert -auto-orient -thumbnail 160 $i thumb-$i; done;
```

And that worked.

Now I would like to have both steps in one and same loop.

Here's the question: can I pipe the data/image coming from `convert` to the `base64` (linux-)function, instead of saving it to file (thumb-)?

Later, it would be appended to textfile ("html" file).

I would gladly take an answer, that shows this (the loop isn't needed).

Here are the named files, and their content:

**html_head.txt**

```
<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>
```

**html_image_cell_start.txt**

```
<img src="

html_image_cell_end.txt

">
```

**html_foot.txt**

```
</body> </html>
```

Comment: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: I'm not the right guy to ask... yet

Comment: I'm not asking, this is a title. Follow the link and you will find out your code is… strange.

Comment: I just tried making the first line like this: echo cat html_head.txt > thumbs_gallery.html and the target file got this text: cat html_head.txt, while doing it with $() gave me the right text.

Comment: `cat html_head.txt > thumbs_gallery.html`

Comment: Thank you Kamil, I have edited two lines (first last), since they were not inside the main question and I can't see how I could edit the middle line in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Imagemagick commandline](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)

```
 convert -auto-orient -thumbnail 160 $i jpg:- | base64
```

Comment: Great! Now I have 3 lines that makes a "thumbs-gallery" when beeing run in a folder with jpeg-images, you want to see? Thanks