# -v unary conditional expression isn't working

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh

I want to check if the given variable is set with the `-v` check. I'm struggling to understand where the error is coming from. Having the following script in a file `var-test.sh`:

```bsh
MY_VAR="test"

if [ -v MY_VAR ]; then
  echo "MY_VAR set to $MY_VAR"
else
  echo "MY_VAR not set"
fi
```

when I run it: `./var-test.sh` I get the following output:

```
./var-test.sh: line 3: [: -v: unary operator expected
MY_VAR not set
```

But when I invoke the following command in the shell prompt:

```
MY_VAR="test"; if [ -v MY_VAR ]; then echo "MY_VAR set to $MY_VAR"; else; echo "MY_VAR not set"; fi
```

the shell doesn't complain about the `-v` operator and outputs `"MY_VAR set to test"` as expected. What gives? Am I missing something obvious?

I thought it's because of using single brackets. When I switch to using double brackets:

```bsh
MY_VAR="test"

if [[ -v MY_VAR ]]; then
  echo "MY_VAR set to $MY_VAR"
else
  echo "MY_VAR not set"
fi
```

I get the following error:

```
./var-test.sh: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
./var-test.sh: line 3: syntax error near `MY_VAR'
./var-test.sh: line 3: `if [[ -v MY_VAR ]]; then'
```

The output of `zsh --version`:

```
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)
```

Comment: What does `man zsh` say? If that manpage just slightly resembles what `man bash` contains - then you might wish to use the (less -command) `/`-key to enter something to search for, maybe `VARIABLE EXPRESSION` for example.

Comment: You seem to miss a shebang (`#!/bin/zsh`) line in your script, so maybe it's not executed with zsh?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly choose an interpreter by specifying a [shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/108618). There is no shebang in your current script. When called from `zsh` [such script runs with `sh`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373229/108618). Apparently whatever provides `sh` in your system does not support `[ -v …`. Zsh supports this, Bash supports this, other shells may not.

It seems you want to use Zsh, so the shebang should be `#!/bin/zsh` or similar. It must be the very first line of the script.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Why does it work though if I use `#!/bin/zsh` shebang, but it doesn't if I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang? When I add the following line: `echo $($SHELL --version)`, it gives exactly the same output in both cases (`zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`), but the `bash` version still fails on the `-v` check.

Comment: OK I've got it. Echoing these two variables in the script: `$BASH_VERSION`, `$ZSH_VERSION` produces the following output:
- in case of `#!/usr/bin/env bash`: `$BASH_VERSION` is `3.2.57(1)-release` (`$ZSH_VERSION` is empty)
- in case of `#!/bin/zsh`: `$ZSH_VERSION` is `5.7.1` (`$BASH_VERSION` is empty)

Comment: @mjarosie `$SHELL` is not the shell you're in. [It's your login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277944/108618). That's why the same output (and [`echo` here is weird](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)). Since Zsh mentions `apple-darwin` then [maybe your Bash is old](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/197172). It seems [you need Bash 4.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56837/108618).

Comment: Thanks Kamil, there's obviously a lot for me to catch up in terms of knowledge about differences between shells and how it's all set up. Thanks for all the links as well!