# Is there any way to display terminal output value on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) window top bar (GNOME Shell)?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, ubuntu-20.04

First of all, I just need to view the outcome of `vnstat -t` continually. This command terminal output looks like this:

[image: Output]

I tried using a tool called "Argos". I created an Argos script to display the terminal output value as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(vnstat -t)"
```

But it looks like this:

[image: Argos output]

I need this type of view:
[image]

However, I need to track daily internet usage (download & upload).
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Side note: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: Please replace all linked images with its text. [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: [link](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2702526/21953508/7463004c-da5f-11e6-99e1-b8db1167c071.gif)  _**i need this type of view**_

Answer (score 0):

migh it be that `vnstat` reduces the output when it detects that a pipe is used?

Try using this:

```
#!/bin/bash
vnstat -t
```

as your "Argos script" - does that remedy your "problem"?

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2702526/21953508/7463004c-da5f-11e6-99e1-b8db1167c071.gif   
i need this type of view