# Echo all the output from a ls command

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have the follow files in my folder:

```
a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg
```

And I have the follow script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

If I run:

```
script.sh $(ls)
```

My output is:

```
a.jpg
```

But I want to be:

```
a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg
```

So, Why doesn't `echo` prints all the output from `ls`?

Comment: (1) Are you sure you run `script.sh "$(ls)"`, not `script.sh $(ls)`? (2) Is this an exercise just to see how Bash behaves? If not then just run `ls` because [what you're doing is unnecessarily complicated](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690).

Comment: (1) Yes you're right, I forgot the quotes, sorry. (2) Yes, is an exercise, I'm trying to understand how works spaces and new lines in bash, that's confusing for me.

Comment: Replace `$1` with `$@`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you explicitly ask to echo only the first argument:

```
echo $1
```

If you would ask for the second argument

```
echo $2
```

you'd get `b.jpg` as output.

You can get all the files using `echo $*` or `echo "$@"`.

Another option is that you make sure that the complete output of `ls` is packed in the first argument. You can do that by adding quotes around it.

```
script.sh "$(ls)"
```