# Why does echo $(TZ=GMT+17 date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) show me yesterday?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, time, date-time, date

When I run this command today, November 8, 2023 at 1100 GMT, the output is: 20231107180000:

```
echo $(TZ=GMT+17 date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

I would have thought that, if anything, GMT+17 would ADD 17 hours to the current time and thus the output would be: 20231109030000. Why does it show me yesterday?

Thanks.

Comment: This exactly: [*Why does TZ=UTC-8 produce dates that are UTC+8?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104088/108618) And you [don't need `echo`](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690). Try `TZ=foo+17 date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I had not found that page. Solved!